# calculate percent of sample in overlapping distributions

Tags: normal-distribution, finite-mixture-model, overlapping-data

I'm looking at 80k samples representing results of a test after a fixed period of time.  I think it looks like a combination of normal curves.

I see a fair amount of documentation about combining two normal distributions  when you are given the distribution properties, where I'm having trouble is determining the distribution properties from the data.

[image]

Can I use this data to figure out what kind of function I'm actually looking at, and, if it is a combination of distributions, generate the descriptive statistics for each?

Comment: Could you elaborate on the connection you see between characterizing a distribution and "forecasting future samples"?  The answer to your last question, by the way, is trivial: yes, of course there's a single function that can describe the whole thing.  It's just going to be a little complicated to write down.

Comment: >elaborate on the connection you see between characterizing a distribution and "forecasting future samples", -> sorry pretty much the same thing.  I'd like to have the function generated by the data, if possible.

Comment: I don't totally understand what you're trying to do, but you might look at http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/mixture.html and see if it is helpful.

Comment: This is time series data and I'm trying to calculate a probability cone for future samples.

Comment: Ah, never mind about the Gaussian mixture model then.  I haven't tried Prophet https://facebookincubator.github.io/prophet/ but it has received some press recently.  Maybe it's worth checking out.

Comment: So is the x-axis in your plot time? I'm confused by this.

Comment: These are results of 1 start state after a fixed time period, I'd like the data to give me a formula I can use to compare with results from different starting states.  I'd also like to use the formula to predict the probability of a particular result happening.